# I want to store additional data on the "submit_transaction" using transact on the api object

Tags: eosjs, testnet, blockchains, blocks

I am new to the eosio platform. My goal is to store additional data onto the testnet.eos.io  and receive a transaction_id which I managed to do. However on searching my transaction_id I see my additional data not showing.

I am using eos.js. What I tried:

```
(async () => {

  const transaction = await api.transact({

   actions: [{

     account: 'eosio',
     name: 'buyrambytes',
     authorization: [{
       actor: 'useraaaaaaaa',
       permission: 'active',
     }],
     data: {
       payer: 'useraaaaaaaa',
       receiver: 'useraaaaaaaa',
       bytes: 8192,
       name:"t",
       roll:45
     },
   }]
  }, {
   blocksBehind: 3,
   expireSeconds: 30,
  });
})();
```

so once I get my transaction ID I check it on the testnet.io and see that only the payer, receiver and bytes show up but not the name and roll. My goal focuses on storing the additional data and receiving the transactionID.

Answer (score 0):

Since buyrambytes action interface is defined with only 3 parameters: payer, receiver and bytes, the rest of the parameters you send are ignored.

What you can do, is write your own contract with buyrambytes action, which accepts all the parameters you need and issues an inline action to eosio::buyrambytes action.

The inline action and your implemented action will both have the same transaction hash, and you will be able to get your extra info in testnet.io